# C++ defining variables setting values

Tags: c++, class, struct

Suppose I have some struct, could be anything:

```
    struct Object{
    int a;
    int b;
    void func(int);
};
```

How would I set something like:

```
int Object::*(int *)
```

equal to some value? any value?

if I have something like int Object::* I can easily just do something like:

```
int Object::*x = &Object::a;
```

etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a reference or pointer to a member? Or a function pointer? I'm not sure I understand the question. What problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `func` returned `int` you could do

```
int Object::*(int *) foo = &Object::func;
```

But as it stands there are no members of Object which are member functions taking a pointer to `int` and returning `int`, so you can't initialise a pointer to one to anything other than null.